# Express server static folder does not serve files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app there are some static files I would like to serve to the client, but the server does not respond.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
```

This is the relevant piece of code I can't fix alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the comma - `,` between `__dirname` and `/public`.

You should change to that:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Uni_Nake suggested using prefix before public folder

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the use of `app.use` and `express.static` are being messed up.  The code you have will serve the whole of the current directory under `/` via express, which i doubt is what you want.

the following will make everything within `/public` available under `/public` :

`app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

i.e. if you have `/public/banner.gif` you'll be able to access it through:

`http://localhost:{port}/pubic/banner.gif`

or you could use the following to and omit the `/public` from the http request:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

i.e. if you have `/public/banner.gif` you'll be able to access it through:

`http://localhost:{port}/banner.gif`